# Как узнать, какой GroupBox принадлежит радиокнопка? (C# Windows Forms)

Tags: c#, winforms

У меня есть несколько Groupbox'ов, в них по несколько радиокнопок. Например, пишу обработчик щелчка на одну из радиокнопок. Как определить, какому именно группбоксу она принадлежит?

Answer (score 1):

```
GroupBox groupBox = null;
Control current = (Control)sender;
while (current != null)
{
  if (current is GroupBox)
  {
    groupBox = (GroupBox)current;
    break;
  }
  current = current.Parent;
}

if (groupBox != null)
{
  // found parent GroupBox
}
```

Comment: используйте лучше приведение типов через `as`, cast при невозможности привидения кинет исключение

Comment: @rdorn если `sender` в обработчике не `Control` - то так ему и надо